# Comparing columns in separate file column by column

Tags: awk

I'm trying to compare two different files, let's say "file1" and "file2", column by column
Fields $1 and $2 are the same in both files, If any value is different in one column, then print columns 1 and 2 and the column number where the mismatch was found, als print the value found in the last column with line error.

**`file1`**

```
36829.00  37145.00  10801  36840.00 36888.00  37146.00  37576 5 1 
36833.00  38033.00  21601  36840.00 36888.00  37602.00  38464 5 1
37265.00  38105.00  25921  36840.00 36900.00  37674.00  38536 6 2
37271.00  38885.00   8841  36840.00 36876.00  38454.00  38894 4 3
```

**`file2`**

```
36829.00  37145.00  10801  36840.00 36888.00  37146.00  37576 5 1
36833.00  38033.00  21601  36840.00 36888.00  37602.00  38464 3 1
37265.00  38105.00  25921  36840.00 36900.00  37674.00  38536 6 2
37271.00  38885.00   8840  36840.00 36876.00  38454.00  38894 4 3
```

**`Desired output`**

Mismatch in # ( **#** is the value of the last column in the line with error )

```
Mismatch in 1: 36833.00  38033.00 column 8
Mismatch in 3: 37271.00  38885.00 column 4
```

**`I tried`**

```
awk 'NR==FNR{a[$1,$2];next} ($1,$2) in a' file1 file2
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Could you please try following(if I got it your question correctly, based on your samples only). This should take care of multiple mismatches on a single line too(lets say there are 3rd and 5th columns mismatches in a line then it will print both of them).

```
awk '
FNR==NR{
  a[FNR]=$0
  b[FNR]=$1 OFS $2
  next
}
{
  num=split(a[FNR],array," ")
  for(i=3;i<=num;i++){
     if($i!=array[i]){
        val=(val?val ",":"")i
     }
  }
  if(val){
     print "Mismatch in line" FNR": " b[FNR]" column(s) "val
     val=""
  }
}'   Input_file1  Input_file2
```

Output will be as follows.

```
Mismatch in line2: 36833.00 38033.00 column(s) 8
Mismatch in line4: 37271.00 38885.00 column(s) 3
```

Comment: Mr RavinderSingh13, Thanks for the code it works perfectly, appreciate your help

Answer (score 3):

Here's one matching on files' record numbers:

```
awk '
NR == FNR {
    a[FNR] = $0                  # match on FNR, you could use a[$1, $2]
    next
}
{
    n = split(a[FNR], b, FS)
    for (i = 3; i <= n; i++) {
        if (b[i] != $i) {
            printf "Mismatch in %d: %s %s column %d\n", FNR, $1, $2, i
        }                        # for 0 starting record numbering use FNR-1 above
    }
}' file1 file2
```

Output:

```
Mismatch in 2: 36833.00 38033.00 column 8
Mismatch in 4: 37271.00 38885.00 column 3
```

Comment: James, Thanks for the code it works fine, appreciate your help

Answer (score 1):

try gnu awk:

```
awk 'NR==FNR{r[NR]=$0;next}{x=split(r[FNR],a);for(i=3;i<=9;i++){if($i!=a[i]) print "Mismatch in "a[9]": "$1,$2" column "i}}' file1 file2
```